# WebClient no response and exception

Tags: c#, .net

Using WebClient to call a post API:

```
try {
  var webClient = new WebClient(); 
  var result= webClient.UploadString('http://wewe.com/name', {...})
  //log1
} catch(Exception ex) {
  //log2
}
```

Sometime I hit a problem that log1 and log2 is not log. No response and exception after http call? Any reason why?

Comment: That sounds peculiar. Please post a minimal, complete reproduce of your problem.

Comment: Try to catch WebException

Comment: what would happen if you would add a log entry before var webClient = new WebClient();

Comment: It will log if is before var result= webClient.UploadString('http://wewe.com/name', {...})

Answer (score -2):

The WebException will give you the answer. Just read the message and inner exception.

Example:

```
string URI = "http://www.myurl.com/post.php";
try
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI);
    }
catch (WebException webex)
{
            WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
            using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
}
```

Comment: I taught WebException is a subset of Exception.

Comment: I agree in general, but actually Kev Fixx with WebClient you have to catch WebException before Exception to get all information. If you only use exception you will not get the correct message.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? How can you down vote? I have used it in several projects.

Comment: @Naha This is not true. Since `WebException` is a `Exception` it will be caught anyway. If there is another exception occurring before `WebException` then there is another problem. Basically what you did is catching specific exception for specific login, it doesn't mean that it will be caught before any other exception.

Comment: @Kamo: I agree, but it was not what I meant. The only thing i meant was that you have to catch the WebException. If not you cannot get the correct error message. In addition the sequence of exception catching above is correct. it is not an an general exception catching issue we are solving here.

Comment: @Naha Yes indeed, that's why I have only commented. You have done this a nice way, the "dirty" way would be to check `ex is WebException` and perform some logic there.

Comment: @Naha why do you have an empty catch(Exception ex) block? it looks like "Error Hiding", which is a bad idea

Comment: @symbiont This is just an example and I will not keep this empty in real code. The catch exception will catch all other exceptions not specified above. This is how exception handling is performed. The important catch in this code is WebException.

Comment: @Naha i would remove the empty catch clause from the example. it doesn't even have comments about why it's empty (the person that asked the question added comments to his too). it looks really bad. if you catch an exception then you should handle it. if you don't know how to handle it, then you should let it propagate. also, `WebException.Response` can be `null` when the source of the error is not a response, but you don't check for `null`